# Unable to view download to browser option for data extension. Another user in my environment is able to view this but not me

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am not able to see the download to browser option and can only see download to ftp option. another user of same environment is able to see this option.

Comment: Same Dataextension? If the DataExtension gets to big salesforce won't give you the option to download via browser.

Comment: Yes same DE... the de file size is less than 20mb and thats why want to do a browser download.... there has to be a setting around this but am unable to find..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the issue is either related to your browser or your user permissions.

I would try using Incognito mode if you're using Chrome or clearing cache and cookies and then see if the browser download option is available.

Check this link for more troubleshooting steps - [Troubleshoot issues in Google Chrome](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312846&type=1&mode=1)

If that doesn't work then I'd compare your permissions to the user who is able to see the browser download option to see if you're missing something.